# Replace \n with a text wrap with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh

I have accessed a file server with SSH. After that I read the folders with `ls` and wrote them into a file. Unfortunately it writes me `\n` with in the file instead of a newline, how can I replace that? I have tried it several ways, the problem was that when I split it directly, it puts each letter on its own line.

```
def writeInFile(self, text):
    outputFile = open("output.txt", "w")
    outputFile.write(text)
    outputFile.close()
    pass
```

Current output:

> ['folder1\n', 'folder2\n', 'folder3\n', 'folder4\n']

Desired output

> folder1 
> folder2 
> folder3 
> folder4

Comment: The data is fine; the problem is that you are passing it in as a list, and `write` writes it out in the format Python writes a list because you haven't specified any other representation. The simple and straightforward solution is to loop over the list and write one element at a time, or change your code to join the list into a single string before calling your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also try this..

```
text = text.replace(r"\n", "\n")
```

add this line before
`outputFile.write(text_to_write)`
this line

The replace statement takes two parameters... : the first is the text you want to replace and the other is the replaced text you want to add...

you can also add the replace statement for `[]` and for `''`

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know if it works:

```
text_to_write = '\n'.join(['folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3', 'folder4'])
outputFile = open("output.txt", "w")
outputFile.write(text_to_write)
outputFile.close()
```

That way, a string is being formed from the list where a newline character is appended to every entry in the list except for the last one, which gives `'folder1\nfolder2\nfolder3\nfolder4'` as the output, which seems to be what you're after.

Comment: I tried it, the problem is that when I try the example with the folders, it works, but when I try it with the real data, each character is written in a separate line.
`[`
`'`
`F`
`o`
`l`
`d`
...